# Vector Summation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, vectors

When two vectors are sketched from a single point, the angle between them is θ.  Show that the size of their vector summation is given in the expression: $ \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 +2ABcosθ} $.

Any suggestions on how one might tackle this one?

Comment: (1) It's probably in your text. (2) Even if not I'm sure this question has been answered on this site. (3) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html.

Comment: as for num 1, no, and as for no 2, no also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is convenient to define the x-axis as being parallel to one of the vectors.  Let us define the x-axis (or i-direction) to be in the direction of vector A.  Let us choose the y-axis (j-direction) to be perpendicular to the x-axis.

Therefore we can write vector A in terms of its i (x-component) and j (y-component) components:

$A = A\hat{i} + 0\hat{j}$

This is because A only has a component in the i-direction (i.e., along the x-axis, by our definition, and has no component along the y-axis by our definition)

Now let us consider vector B.

The x-component of B will be:

$B\cos{\theta}$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the $A$ vector and the $B$ vector, which also happens to be the angle between the $B$ vector and the x-axis, since we chose our x-axis to coincide with the A vector.

Similarly the y-component of B will be:

$B\sin{\theta}$

Therefore,

$B = B\cos{\theta}\hat{i} + B\sin{\theta}\hat{j}$

Adding A and B thus gives,

$A + B = (A + B\cos{\theta})\hat{i} + B\sin{\theta}\hat{j}$

The length of a vector is the square root of the x-component squared plus the y-comopnent squared (pythagorus' theorem).  Therefore the length of A + B is:

$Length^2 = (A + B\cos{\theta})^2 + (B\sin{\theta})^2  = A^2 + 2AB\cos{\theta} + B^2\cos^2 {\theta} + B^2\sin^2{\theta} = A^2 + 2AB\cos{\theta} + B^2(\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta) = A^2 + 2AB\cos{\theta} + B^2$

The last equation follow from the identity that $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$

Therefore,

$Length = \sqrt{A^2 + 2AB\cos{\theta} + B^2}$

QED